# Ruby & Ruby on Rails versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Ruby v2.5.1 and Rails 5.2.3 installed and I am planning to upgrade Ruby to 3.0.0.

Do I need to upgrade Rails to a higher version?

Are there any checks I can perform to make sure they are both compaibile?

Answer (score 1):

You need at least `Rails 6.0.3` to work with `Ruby 3.0`.

Changelog for `Rails 6.0.3` contains this note:

```
This version fixes warnings when used with Ruby 2.7.
```

Related discussion about compatibility:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40938

---

Even if you update your Rails to 6.X, update Ruby to 2.7 and fix all warnings before upgrading to Ruby 3.0.

About warnings: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/